# Android browser Push notifications when browser is not open

Tags: android, google-chrome, push-notification

i want to implement push notifications when browser is not open in android, now when the user has signed up for the notifications is it possible to send them notifications just like any normal app without opening browser?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? We want to help you with problems you have, we don't want to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the most expertised in this area. As I use native for my push notification handling. You could of course use React-Native, Ionic, Phone Gap or any other number of web wrapping tools to have your own app handle PUSH notifications.

However, i know there are some libraries out there that claim to help with this, might be worth a shot.

https://pushcrew.com/mobile-website-push-notifications-android/

I'm not entirely sure of their requirements, if they rely on Chrome or not, and if they will work if the web browser is killed is another unknown, but worth looking into.